# Breeze + Web API 2 OData - 406 error when entity namespace doesn't match dbcontext

Tags: breeze

I was following the example here:

http://www.breezejs.com/samples/breeze-web-api-odata

And I had begun to split the entity framework bits out into its own library (.Data.Ef)

I noticed when I changed the DBContext's namespace to something that didn't match exactly what the entities/models had the server started throwing 406 "Not Acceptable" errors.

Is this intended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The model binding cannot work if the request doesn't match what the class fullnames. You might as well have asked it to query or save the `Foo` class